# Which one is a best design making one single HTTP request or multiple small HTTP request?

Tags: ajax, angular, api, http, request

I am creating a angular application where I need to display count of individual number of animals.

For example:

My backend data based has animals stored as like

```
{ id: 1, name: "lion" },{ id: 2, name: "lion" },{ id: 3, name: "lion" },
{ id: 4, name: "tiger" }, { id: 5, name: "tiger" }, { id: 6, name: "wolf" }
```

Then I need to display

3 lions
2 tigers
1 wolf

I have /animals:GET end point which returns all the animals.

Response:

```
{
  totalCount: 6,
  animals: [
{ id: 1, name: "lion" },{ id: 2, name: "lion" },{ id: 3, name: "lion" },
{ id: 4, name: "tiger" }, { id: 5, name: "tiger" }, { id: 6, name: "wolf" }
  ]
}
```

With this requirement which is a better design

1. Making one single request /animals:GET without any additional params
2. Making multiple chunks of requests /animals?name=lion and /animals?name=tiger and /animals?name=wolf

Comment: There is a lot of information on this subject as this is not framework specific. Have you searched a bit?

Comment: Is the duplicate id 4 a typo?

Comment: Yes 4 is a typo

Answer (score 1):

It's better to make a single request to the server that gives you all of the data you need in one go. A single call will be quicker than multiple sequential ones.

A good analogy is one of going to the shop. If you have to retrieve 10 items you end up carrying the same amount of weight (i.e. data) regardless of whether you go once or go 10 times, however, going 10 times involves the effort of 10 trips.

It's the same with server requests. Your client has to create a connection to the server, request data, the server gets a connection from a pool, the DB has to seek out indexes for your data to retrieve. If you did this once then it would all happen as a single operation rather than all of these things happening 10 times.

Comment: Can you please explain me why single request is better than multiple request?

Answer (score 0):

Well it depends on what type of data you want and how you want. Single request is always better than multiple request as your server has to do less work so less performance issue if your app scales up.

If you want to fetch all animals make a single request but if you want to fetch 3-4 animals than you can create multiple request or make a single request by passing a array as param